# Effective ACL permissions changing permissions

Tags: bash, command-line, permissions, acl

From a bash shell script, I am creating a folder and storing the mysqldump there. I am sure that there is no command related to permissions in my script. To allow an other user to access these files, I have used ACL, but when he tried to access the file, he got permission denied issue, and issue is with `effective` permissions of ACL.

The owner of the directory is `ola` and new user who is trying to access the folder is `uber` and folder is `gettaxi`

#### Permissions of Parent directory

```
[/omega/olabooktmp]# getfacl .
# file: .
# owner: ola
# group: ola
user::rwx
user:uber:rwx
group::r-x
mask::rwx
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:user:uber:rwx
default:group::r-x
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

#### Permissions of Child directory

```
[/omega/olabooktemp]# getfacl gettaxi/
# file: gettaxi/
# owner: ola
# group: ola
user::rwx
user:uber:rwx       #effective:---
group::r-x          #effective:---
mask::---
other::---
default:user::rwx
default:user:uber:rwx
default:group::r-x
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

I see like for new directory `gettaxi` mask permissions are `mask::---`, so I think this is causing issue, but I am unable to understand completely and how to solve this issue.

Any suggestions greatly appreicated.

Thank you.

Comment: related to https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/570795/4778

Answer (score 0):

You can change the mask with the following command:

```
setfacl -m m:rwx filename/directory
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well your question, user `ola` is creating files in directory: `/omega/olabooktmp/gettaxi`

and you want to restrict access to thoses files, but granting access to user `uber`.

Note: `/omega/olabooktmp/gettaxi` is owned by `ola`

Lets start without ACL yet:

```
ls -ld /omega/olabooktmp/gettaxi
drwxr-x--- 2 ola ola 4096 mars  21 08:16 /omega/olabooktmp/gettaxi
```

In order to grant `rwx` permission to `uber` using ACL you can use:

```
setfacl -m u:uber:rwx,d:u:uber:rwX,o:--- /omega/olabooktmp/gettaxi
```

Which will allow user `uber` rights `rwx` on folder `/omega/olabooktmp/gettaxi`, and also grant `rwx` as `default` the `d:` and `X`. It grants permission on files previously presents in the folder and give inherited grants to file. And also remove other all permission to `other` for restriction, of course. Owner still have its own permission.

The result:

```
getfacl /omega/olabooktmp/gettaxi
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: omega/olabooktmp/gettaxi
# owner: ola
# group: ola
user::rwx
user:uber:rwx
group::r-x
mask::rwx
other::---
default:user::rwx
default:user:uber:rwx
default:group::r-x
default:mask::rwx
default:other::---
```

Testing:

`ola` creates some files (run as root):

```
su - ola -c "for i in {1..3}; do date > /omega/olabooktmp/gettaxi/$RANDOM; done"
```

Result:

```
ls -l /omega/olabooktmp/gettaxi/
total 32
-rw-r----- 1 ola users 32 mars  21 08:43 17606
-rw-r----- 1 ola users 32 mars  21 08:43 22286
-rw-r----- 1 ola users 32 mars  21 08:42 31484
-rw-r----- 1 ola users 32 mars  21 08:43 31848
-rw-r----- 1 ola users 32 mars  21 08:42 667
-rw-r----- 1 ola users  4 mars  21 08:16 one
-rw-r----- 1 ola users  6 mars  21 08:16 three
-rw-r----- 1 ola users  4 mars  21 08:16 two
```

Can't be accessed by a normal user (run as root):

```
su - debian -c "ls -l /omega/olabooktmp/gettaxi"
ls: cannot open directory '/omega/olabooktmp/gettaxi': Permission denied
```

But uber can (run as root):

```
su - uber -c "ls -l /omega/olabooktmp/gettaxi"
total 32
-rw-r----- 1 ola users 32 Mar 21 08:43 17606
-rw-r----- 1 ola users 32 Mar 21 08:43 22286
-rw-r----- 1 ola users 32 Mar 21 08:42 31484
-rw-r----- 1 ola users 32 Mar 21 08:43 31848
-rw-r----- 1 ola users 32 Mar 21 08:42 667
-rw-r----- 1 ola users  4 Mar 21 08:16 one
-rw-r----- 1 ola users  6 Mar 21 08:16 three
-rw-r----- 1 ola users  4 Mar 21 08:16 two
```

If you mangle your ACL with some tests, you can remove all acl with:

```
setfacl -R -b /omega/olabooktmp/gettaxi
```

And start again.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the mask is lowering the permissions. The effective permission is the and of a permission and the mask. (`user::` (the owning user), and `other` are not affected by the mask).

You can change the mask with: e.g. `setfacl -m m:r-x file-name`.

When you do an `ls -l`, if the mode ends with a `+`, then the middle mode bits (traditionally the group bits), are the mask.

Sometimes the mode bits are set according to the group bits in `umask`. I have not yet worked out the rules, as to when this happens, and when the default mask is used. Using `cp` to copy a file, seems to use the `umask`.

## A workaround

Ensure that users have there own group, and that this is set to the default group. Then set the `umask` to  `007`.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the behavior is a bug. I posted on this last month (see unix.stackexchange.com/questions/570795).  What is happening is that the file permissions on the source file are being copied into the acl mask by the cp command. This is what I would have expected for cp -p, not cp.  I found that I can do copies by using cat

```
cat afile > bfile
```

or by piping through tar

`(cd A; tar -cf -)|(cd B; tar-xf -)`

And the acls are respected as expected.

I also put up a bounty to have this cp behavior explained. No one explained it. I'm thinking of filing a bug report.  I.e. that this should be the ´cp -p´ behavior, not the vanilla cp behavior. (And the system deducted the bounty points even though no one could provide an answer.  I was surprised by that also.)