# What is the full list of rules that defines permissions on a newly created file in a directory?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, directory

I have a directory that has `rwxrwxr-x` and `-s-` permission settings, if I create files in this folder from user A these files gets permission `rw-rw-r--`, and with user B it gets `rw-r--r--`. I'm really confused about how exactly files are getting their permission set when they are first created...

To be more focused on what i need to do - the directory has group G which contains both users A and B and I want them both to be able to work on all the files in that same directory, so if both of them would have created files with `rw-rw-r--` they could work on these files (delete them and recreate them or just edit them) without interference.

Comment: So is the mode `drwxrwsr-x`?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor yes

Comment: Set-group-id just sets the group. The mode is controlled by the `umask`. There was a question a, few days ago, about file-access-control-lists FACLs, that may be relevant. https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/570795/4778 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/573349/4778

Answer (score 1):

The permissions of a new file are set from (1) the permissions set in the `open()` call modified by (2) the `umask` of the creating process, so that bits set in the `umask` are zeroed. That is, a permission bit is set only if allowed by both of those, it's just that the bits in `umask` are inverted.

In your case the users probably have different umasks, namely A seems to have an umask of `0002` (clearing just the write bit from others), while B seems to have an umask of `0022` (clearing the write bit from the group and other users). The umasks are likely set in their shell startup files or via `pam_umask`.

If you have ACLs set on the directory, and default ACLs in particular, then the situation is slightly different. In that case, the umask is ignored, and instead the default ACLs are copied to ACLs on the file, except that only permission bits set in the system call stay set.

You're probably looking for the answers in this question:

- [Make all new files in a directory accessible to a group](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/12842/170373)