# RHEL installation time cannot set user with group id 100

Tags: system-installation, installer-anaconda

when installing `rhel-8.9-x86_64-dvd.iso`, and even version 7.9, at the initial graphical popup during install when you go to `user creation - advanced` ...

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/installation_guide/sect-configuration-progress-menu-ppc

[image]

I can set a user id manually to my liking, **but why when I try to set a manual group id it will not allow you to use gid 100** (which is the *users* group) ?

After install, as root I do

- edit `/etc/passwd` and change the gid for `jdoe` in this example to `100`
- `groupdel jdoe` because it will have automatically created a group name based on the username with a unique id.
- `chown -R jdoe.users /home/jdoe`

**is there some new convention now where we should not be using the `users` group?**  Why does this prohibition happen with RHEL 8.9 (and 7.9) when I want to say back around RHEL 7.5 days this was not the case and I could set gid to 100 here; this also happens during install of CentOS or Rocky.

Comment: What happens if you type `100 `in the **Group Membership** textbox.  You cant "set" a group ID that already exists, but you can add it.

Comment: See also: [Why does every user have their own group?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153390/why-does-every-user-have-their-own-group)